# Laravel 5.4 Storage link

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i would like to show a picture in html file i go to the link folder 
    public/storage/image is empty but in the storage/image i find the file and 
    its also saved in the data base.*

```
@foreach($cvs as $cv)
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$cv->photo) }}" alt="...">
                        <div class="caption">
                        <h3>{{ $cv->titre }}</h3>
                        <p>{{$cv->presentation}}</p>
                        <p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Afficher</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Modifier</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Supprimer</a>
                         </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                    </div>
               </div>
```

Comment: Is this the actual directory `public/storage/image`?

Comment: i created by this command " php artisan storage:link "

Answer (score 32):

First of all in the ***.env file*** create a variable named **FILESYSTEM_DRIVER** and set it to **`public`** like this

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
```

and then create symbolic link by run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

after that just use asset()

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$cv->photo) }}" alt="...">
```

It'll work fine

Comment: Hey I was stuck for many hours. The internet was full of advice on creating storage link but I didnt read anywhere about the FILESYSTEM_DRIVER. This solved it for me. Thank you

Comment: Using laravel 8 is not necessary the FILESYSTEM_DRIVER variable

Answer (score 9):

Go to public directory and run:

```
rm storage
```

Then go to project root and  run:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 6):

The `public` disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the  `public` disk uses the local driver and stores these files in `storage/app/public`. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to  `storage/app/public`. [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem)

Create Symbolic link in [Linux](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abbe)

```
ln -s source_file myfile
```

Comment: also `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: of course i use php artisan storage:link and the folder created in public/storage/image and dosn t work when i would like to show the file because public/storage/image empty

Comment: recommended: php artisan storage:link

Answer (score 4):

solved it with just a simple modification on the filesystems config/file systems
from :

```
'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ]
```

to :

```
'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        ]
```

Answer (score 2):

if you're unable to create symblink on LAMP via running

```
php artisan storage:link
```

then run

```
 ln -s public_html/storage/app/public public_html/public/storage
```

if your not in public_html or at root folder then run

```
  ln -s /application/xyhpnqyw/public_html/storage/app/public /application/xyhpnqyw/public_html/public/storage
    target='/application/xyhpnqyw/public_html/storage/app/public'
    shortcut='/application/xyhpnqyw/public_html/public/storage'
```

then run these commands

Answer (score 1):

As Mayank Majithya notes, a symbolic link is one common way to access `storage/app/public/` files from the `public/` directory, and in fact the method [the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk) say you should use.

If you are on shared hosting that disallows this, you could also try to use Laravel's `storage_path()` helper function, like so: `<img src="{{ storage_path('subpaths/under/storage/filename.jpg') }}">` ([reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-storage-path)).

I also notice you mention the images are stored in the database. If you mean the whole file is stored, it may be more efficient (once you have the file path figured out) to store only the file path in your database, rather than the whole file (since it is already stored on disk). You can then use your model to get the path (assuming your table has columns for, say, 'src' and 'alt'):

```
<img src="{{ $mymodel->src }}" alt="{{ $mymodel->alt }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

**This worked for me.** I added the command "Artisan::call('storage:link', [] );" to the beginning of the route file and deleted the storage folder from public.

*It is important to delete the folder first, otherwise it will not work.*

*Removed the code from the route, if it is working, since it should only run once on the server.*

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks!