# How to access image from /storage -laravel- from SPA with vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

if i put an image in "storage/app/public/img/logo.png" and execute:

```
$ php artisan storage:link
```

How i get that logo.png in vue component?

```
<img src="storage/app/public/img/logo.png">
```

The requested it's ok (200) but that image not render, because is an SPA.

Thank you,

Comment: The solution is symbolic links. Check this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50185576/1646997

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, after to do:

```
$ php artisan storage:link
```

In my component i used:

```
<img :src="'../storage/img/logo.png'">
```

thanks,

Comment: What's the workaround for a vuejs frontend that is built using vue-cli and is separate from the laravel backend but both served using the same domain?.

eg. vuejs-frontend -> /var/html/vuejs/dist
      laravel-backend -> /var/html/laravel-backend

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Check `config/filesystems.php` (ie: unmodified default):

```
    // If server doesn't support "making symbolic links":
    // https://medium.com/@shafiya.ariff23/how-to-store-uploaded-images-in-public-folder-in-laravel-5-8-and-display-them-on-shared-hosting-e31c7f37a737
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

> 2. Save an image:

```
   $image = $request->file('image'); // something like that
   $slug = 'some-slug-99';

   $image->storeAs(
       'examples' .'/'. $slug,
       $image->getClientOriginalName(),
       'public'
   );
```

> 3. Create the symlink from `/storage/app/public` to `public/storage` (ie: your public html folder which makes `asset()` work in Laravel Blade templates, I think but don't quote me on that)

```
$ php artisan storage:link
```

> 4. Place the HTML in your Vue component:

```
<img
    v-for="image in example.images"
    :key="image.filename"
    :src="`/storage/examples/${example.slug}/${image.filename}`"
>
```

Also, read the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `storage:link` command, you create a symbolic link between your `storage/app/public` folder and your `public/storage` folder.

So now you can find your files at the url `$BASE_URL/storage/img/logo.png`.

I recommend you to use the `asset` helper function inside your blade template:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/img/logo.png' }}">
```

NOTE: be sure to set the proper file permissions on the folder or you get an `Unauthorized` error when trying to access it.

Comment: This is the best answer it worked for me after running php artisan storage:link then I used in my img path :src="'./storage/profile/' + member.profile_pic" where profile is my folder inside storage/app/public/profile and member.profile_pic is my image. Great THANKS!

Comment: This only works when using blade templates. The original question was asking about accessing the images within a SPA written in Vuejs so this answer is irrelevant and answering a different question

Answer (score 1):

When using `php artisan storage:link` you are creating a simbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`

I'm used to use `asset` instead regular path: Try using `src="{{ asset('storage/app/public/img/logo.png') }}`

It is supposed that if you are using a SPA, when a component renders, it will make a new request to get the img

Answer (score 1):

Hope my answer will help someone,
Create a symbolic link by using this command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

now use it in you vue template as following

```
/storage/path/to/file
```

Comment: Great, thanks! This works!

Answer (score 0):

routes/web.php

For SPA application, Laravel usually render index blade for all incoming requests.

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

I changed this route so that all routes except "/storage/**/*.*" locate index blade page.
This way, you can both render SPA and get uploaded image.

```
Route::any('{all}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('all', '^(?!storage).*$');
```

I assume you have already created symlink using `php artisan storage:link` command.
Take a look [Vue js laravel 8 routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67122395/vue-js-laravel-8-routing)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why no one write their solution clear.
In `Laravel` and `vuejs`
When you store files inside laravel storage do as bellow;

1. create a symlink by running `php artisan storage:link` it will create a directory inside your-project/public by the name of `storage` which is not actually a directory that is a link to `project/storage` directory, if you navigate to your-project/public you will see all the files uploaded into your storage showing here, now you cannot access your file directly from here.
2. If you have an image stored in this location: `storage/app/public/files/logo.png`  the path to show the image in vue a component will be `/storage/files/logo.png` please escape `app/public` parts.
   `<b-avatar href="#" :src="'/storage/files/logo.png'"></b-avatar>`
   I hop it help someone.