# What is best practice for image src in vue SFC?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, vue-component

I am using Laravel 5.8 and Vue 2.6 and trying to use a relative path for an image file in my single file component. I have reviewed the suggestions in [How to import and use image in a Vue single file component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116796/how-to-import-and-use-image-in-a-vue-single-file-component)
but cannot get it to work.

When trying:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

I get this:

> This relative module was not found:
>   * ./assets/logo.png in ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib?
>   ?vue-loader-options!./resources/js/components/xxxx.vue?vue&type=template&id=abd0e146&scoped=true&

When I try:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img :src="image" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import image from "./assets/logo.png"


export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            image: image
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

I get:

> This relative module was not found:
>   * ./assets/logo.png in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--4-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./resources/js /components/xxxx.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

Am I missing something with webpack-mix or vue-loader?

### Edit:

Using simple static reference (src="/assets/logo.png") works on local development server, but doesn't on production server.

I've seen numerous suggested solutions for this basic image file referencing, but puzzled that there are so many possibilities and not a single best practice. Again, hoping to find a Best Practice when using Laravel/Laravel Mix/Vue and SFC that works in development and production.

Comment: How come the error says `logo.jpg` while you're importing `logo.png`

Comment: Sorry, it is a png file. I changed my question to reflect that.

Comment: Where is your image stored? where is it located? full path please

Comment: Laravel 5.8 uses a public folder for deployment. My images are currently in the public folder, so the absolute path is "http://localhost:8000/public/img/widgets/logo.png". The above is simplified for discussion.

Comment: Are you using `php artisan serve`?

Comment: Yes (note port :8000).

Comment: Okay! I reproduced your problem and solved it in the answer below

Comment: Here's a link to my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250712/how-to-access-image-from-storage-laravel-from-spa-with-vuejs/64639576#64639576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is that the wrong deployment for the production server was being used that tried pointing to the 'public' folder instead of locating the public files on public_html.

After deploying according [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868393/laravel-shared-hosting-routes-not-working-properly/46409411#46409411), of course relative paths work exactly the same on development and production servers.

The only difference is in **Step 5** for Laravel 5.8 in the `server.php` file,

***Change***

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}
```

To

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public_html'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}
```

Relative paths like

```
<img src="img/logo.png">
```

on either server work the same.

It's unfortunate that Laravel docs don't go into more detail on this method of deployment since I suspect there are numerous developers wanting to deploy on shared servers at least for testing purposes.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways of using an image in your setup:

## Bundled with webpack

```
<img src="./assets/logo.png">
```

```
import image from "./assets/logo.png"
```

These bundle the image using webpack, and using this solution you get the benefits of:

- Automatic inlinening with base64 for small images
- Automatic "deep" compressing with any webpack loaders
- Path works from every path in your app
- Compile time checking if the file exists

## Using your own webserver

```
const image = '/assets/logo.png'
```

```
const image = 'http://example.com/’
```

In these solutions, you need to setup your webserver yourself to serve those resources (or put them in the public directory)

- Easy changing to a different image without rebuilding the front end
- More flexible

Comment: These don't work. Remember, I'm using Laravel framework with Laravel-mix. I suspect it may be why this prescribed method doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```html
<img src="@/assets/logo.png">
```

This will use webpack and created a hashed version of your logo.png.
Or in JS use:

```js
:src="require('@/assets/logo.png');
```

Comment: That gives me this error: "This dependency was not found:
* @/assets/logo.png in ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib?
?vue-loader-options!./resources/js/components/xxxx.vue?vue&type=template&id=abd0e146&scoped=true&

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that your logo is in the correct path? should be in resources/assets/logo.png

Comment: Thanks, I moved the file into the resources/assets folder. Unfortunately, same result. You said that using the img tag will use webpack to create a hashed version of the png. Do I need to tell webpack to look in the resources folder for assets or does the '@' prefix do that?

Comment: BTW, all references I've seen say to put image files in the public/ folder, not the resources/ folder for Laravel and Larevel Mix.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that your image is stored in public folder and is accessible, you can link to it by absolute path just fine instead of using a relative path `./`

```html
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <img src="/public/img/widgets/logo.png" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

Given you have this structure

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Doesn't work. Compiles ok, but cannot resolve path. Actually, src="/asset/logo.png" works on development server, but not production server. I'm still searching for best practice with Laravel/Vue.

Comment: There's no "path resolution" here, the HTML is output as it is and even if the image doesn't exist at all or the path is completely incorrect, it would still compile, make sure the image is actually on that route, or give me the URL of the image on the server and I will create a sandbox with a vue component correctly showing it

Comment: As stated, this compiles okay and the image does display for src="/asset/logo.png".