# Vue js laravel 8 routing

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, nginx, vue-router

I am still confused when i try to add a route path in vue router such as :

```
{
        path: '/admin/blog/archived_blogs',
        name: 'ArchivedBlogs',
        meta: { title: 'Archived Blog' },
        component: ArchivedBlog
},
```

everything works fine apart from deleting where i get error
405(Method not allowed)

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> GET, HEAD.

all i can do is change the path to

```
{
   path: '/admin_blog_archived_blogs',
   name: 'ArchivedBlogs',
   meta: { title: 'Archived Blog' },
   component: ArchivedBlog
},
```

the current web route i use is

```
Route::get('/{slug?}', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->where('slug', '[\/\w\.-]*')->name('home');
```

Any advice ?

Comment: `Route::get` says it's a GET route, change to `Route::post` if you want a POST route

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `any()` to catch all the methods as well

like

```php
Route::any('/{slug?}', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->where('slug', '[\/\w\.-]*')->name('home');
```

---

for SPA i use

```php
Route::any('{all}', [HomeController::class, 'index'])
    ->where('all', '^(?!api).*$')
    ->where('all', '^(?!storage).*$');
```

like this so all the `web` related route handle `Vuejs` and `storage` or `api` route handel by laravel

Comment: when bringing in Vue router 4 into a Laravel 8 app...is it possible to use Vue Router for some vue components routing and then have completely separate unrelated routing using Laravel 8 web routes? For example in my app Vue router keeps looking for a `/` route when I load my dashboard...but I don't have a Main or Home Vue component...instead I load my Laravel apps dashboard using a web route in Web.php. How do I handle a scenario like this?

Comment: @PA-GW have you tried above solution ?

Comment: I have not...before implementing I wanted to ask if I would need to do this for EVERY single controller/web route I have...which is about 50. I see it applied to a `HomeController::class` above only. Also, how does it know to handle `Vue.js` routes? I see the regex for `api` and `storage` in the `where` clauses but not any regex for `vue`? Thank you for your time!