# How to display an storage image Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-filesystem

I want tho disply an image on my view, but i receive: `File not found`.

The two errors:

> FileNotFoundException in FilesystemAdapter.php line 61:
>   storage/app/public/covers/teste-bravo_cover.jpg
>
> FileNotFoundException in Filesystem.php line 386: File not found at
>   path: storage/app/public/covers/teste-bravo_cover.jpg

But the image is in the correct folder:

[image: a busy cat]
[image: fileOnFolder]

Well, in Laravel 5.2 `storage:link` won't work.

Image store on disk -works fine to store the image

```
if($cover){
            dump("ok1");
            Storage::disk('public_covers')->put($covername, File::get($cover));

            $coverObject = New Cover();      

            //path com o nome do arquivo
            $coverObject->imagePath = 'storage/app/public/covers/'.$covername;
            dump($coverObject->imagePath);
        }

        //Salva a capa com o path para o arquivo
        $coverObject->save();
```

My filesystems (with the "public_covers" disk) -works fine to store the image

```
        'public_covers' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public/covers'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

View code: (if movie have cover, show them)

```
                @if($movie->cover)
                <img src="{{route('cover.image', [$movie->cover])}}" />
                @endif
```

Route code, directing to controller method

```
Route::get('/movieimage/{coverId}',
[
               'as' => 'cover.image',
               'uses' => 'MovieController@getimage'
           ]
);
```

Controller Method to take the image

```
    public function getimage($coverId){
        $movie = Cover::find($coverId);
        //dump($movie);
        $imagePath = $movie['imagePath'];

        dump($imagePath);

        $file = Storage::disk('public_covers')->get($imagePath);

        $response = Response::make($file, 200);
        return $response;     
    }
```

Comment: Try using [asset helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-asset).

Comment: I try to use `<img src="{{asset($movie->cover->imagePath)}}" />`

On browser they show the corect path, but wont load the image.

`<img src="http://localhost:8000/storage/app/public/covers/teste-bravo_cover.jpg">`

Comment: now must use storage links , you can answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185273/laravel-5-4-storage-link)

Comment: storage:link works only after 5.3 version, or not?

I receive this message at run on 5.2
`[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  There are no commands defined in the "storage" namespace.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved my problem:

First of all, save the files on "public" folder.

On my filesystems.php i change my disk. Now my root are "public_path" and not "storage_path"

```
        'public_covers' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('images/covers'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

My controller method

```
    public function store(Request $request){

        $cover = $request->file('cover');
        $inputs = $this->request->all();

        $this->validate($this->request, [
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'description' => 'required',
            'gender' => 'required',
            'secondGender' => 'required',
            'year' => 'numeric|min:1900|max:2100',
            'lenght' => 'numeric|min:10'
        ]);

        //build movie model object
        $movie = New Movie();
        $movie->user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
        $movie->gender_id = $inputs['gender'];
        $movie->secondgender_id = $inputs['secondGender'];
        $movie->title = $inputs['title'];
        $movie->slug = str_slug($inputs['title']);
        $movie->description = $inputs['description'];
        $movie->lenght = $inputs['lenght'];
        $movie->year = $inputs['year'];

        //TODO Mudar a composição do nome da foto para impedir que no futuro se sobreponha uma capa com outro filme que venha a ter o mesmo nome
        //TODO: Change the name createan to avoid overwrite the cover with an movie with the same name
        $covername = str_slug($inputs['title']).'_cover' .'.jpg';

        //if have an cover file
        if($cover){
            //storage the file on my public_covers (look my filesystems.php)
            Storage::disk('public_covers')->put($covername, File::get($cover));
            $coverObject = New Cover();      

            //path com o nome do arquivo
            //path with the file name
            $coverObject->imagePath = 'images/covers/'.$covername;

            $coverObject->save();
            $movie->cover_id = $coverObject->id;
        }

        $movie->save();

        return redirect()
            ->route('user.dashboard')
            ->with([
                       'success' => 'Filme adicionado com sucesso!',
                   ]);
    }
```

My view image code

```
@if($movie->cover)
                <img class="cover" src="{{ asset($movie->cover->imagePath) }}" alt="{{ $movie->title }}"">
                @else
                <img class="cover" src="{{ asset('images/noimage.jpg') }}" alt="{{ $movie->title }}">
                @endif
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try

Need to include this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

And set in controller or route

```
Route::get('storage/{filename}', function ($filename)
{

    $files = Storage::files('logs');  // set repo name of storage folder

    $path = storage_path('public/' . $filename);

    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to laravel. I had the same problem though am on laravel 5.8. I had created the symlink to display a pdf as a view but the `FileNotFoundException` persisted.
I ended up accessing the pdf using this url `localhost:8000/storage/filename.ext`.

After running `ln -s /path/to/laravel/storage/public /path/to/laravel/public/storage` or `php artisan storage:link` a storage folder is added to your `appname/public` directory. I think that once the link is created we access the images in the storage through the public link created. Try accessing the images via the new `/appname/public/storage/app/pathtoimage` folder created in the `public` directory and not pointing directly to the `/appname/storage` folder

```
<img src={{asset('/storage/pathtoimg')}} /> # using storage folder in public
```

[Check this solution will work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view)

Comment: From your first comment, I can see you are trying to access the image directly and not using the link created after running `ln -s /path/to/laravel/storage/public /path/to/laravel/public/storage`